# PHP built-in functions for replace two search str

Tags: php

i'm trying to convert "`/notes/test.php`" to str "`test`"
    using :

```
str_replace("/notes/", "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

result :

```
 test.php
```

i'm looking for PHP Internal function to remove "`/notes/`" AND "`.php`"

Comment: Welcome. `str_replace()` _is_ a PHP internal function and can remove `/notes/` and `.php` from your string.

Comment: `str_replace(["/notes/",".php"], "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP manual for str_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

"*An array may be used to designate multiple needles.*"

So you can use:

```
str_replace(['/notes/', '.php'], '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

to get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You should used `explode` with `str_replace` function like that

```
    $str='/notes/test.php';

    function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
        $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
        $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
        return  $launch;
    }
    // uso
    $str = multiexplode(array("/","."),$str);
//only get your desired data 
    $data=array();
    foreach($str as $value){
        if($value!='notes'){
            $data[]=$value;
        }
    }
    print_r($data);
```

you can check your desired [output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7563508d53931cab6a30c9af02f418278ffeaec0)

if you want to combine then use `implode` function

[Reference and more details](https://gist.github.com/nailton/1c5ad61cc4650fb18b21)

Answer (score 0):

As states in the manual:

```
// Provides: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a case of how to get the name of the script being run, then the problem is that this method will only work if the script is under the `/notes` directory.  So if the script was instead

```
/notes1/test.php
```

as it is in the `/notes1` directory, the replace will fail.

Instead you could use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) which will extract the file name.  I've also forced the name to lower case (in case the file is called using `TEST.PHP` which works on Windows servers I think).  `basename()` will give `test.php` so just remove the `.php` and it should be the proper script name...

```
$name = str_replace(".php", "", strtolower(basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])));
```

If your URL also included parameters (i.e. `/notes/test.php?a=1`, this will also confuse things, so the addition of using `parse_url()` and just extracting the path will cater for this...

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
$name = str_replace(".php", "", strtolower(basename($path)));
```